# Swift: NSStackView, bug only one subview is added

Tags: swift, cocoa

Hello in my code below I want to add NSImageView to my stackView, but there is a bug because there is only one that is added. The loop is 3 iterations so normally I should have 3 images:

```
    let imageView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    imageView.image = image.image

    icons.forEach { _ in
        stackImage.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
    }

    print(stackImage.subviews.count) // Outpout 1
```

Comment: You have only one NSImageView instance. Create NSImageView instance inside the for loop

Comment: You are right thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the NSImageView instances inside the forloop.
And you need to check `stackImage.arrangedSubviews.count` not `stackImage.subviews.count`

```
var icons = [NSImage(named: ""),NSImage(named: ""),NSImage(named: "")]
icons.forEach { image in
    let imageView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    imageView.image = image
    stackImage.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
}
print(stackImage.arrangedSubviews.count)
```